# Add a rounded border to a texture with a fragment shader

Tags: shaders, webgl

I am trying to draw a rounded border / outline around a texture. Basically I have two textures doing a transition and the border should look like being part of the textures itself.

I tried different approaches, but the best I could get is a border that is cut off on the top and only the top right corner being rounded.

The result looks like this:

[image: texture not in the center and only one corner is rounded.]

I have the feeling I am pretty close, but it seems that I am missing something.

Here is my fragment shader code:

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 uImageActiveSize;
uniform vec2 uImageNextSize;
uniform vec2 uPlaneSize;
uniform vec2 uDirection;
uniform float uTransitionProgress;
uniform float uMaskProgress;

uniform float uBorderThickness;
uniform float uBorderRadius;
uniform vec4 uBorderColor;

uniform sampler2D tMapActive;
uniform sampler2D tMapNext;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;

vec4 getFromColor(vec2 uv){return texture2D(tMapActive, uv);}
vec4 getToColor(vec2 uv){return texture2D(tMapNext, uv);}

const float smoothness = 0.5;
const vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);

vec4 transition (vec2 uv) {
  vec2 v = normalize(uDirection);
  v /= abs(v.x) + abs(v.y);
  float d = v.x * center.x + v.y * center.y;
  float m = 1.0 - smoothstep(-smoothness, 0.0, v.x * uv.x + v.y * uv.y - (d - 0.5 - uTransitionProgress * (1.0 + smoothness)));
  return mix(getFromColor((uv - 0.5) * (1.0 - m) + 0.5), getToColor((uv - 0.5) * m + 0.5), m);
}


float calcDistance(vec2 uv) {
    vec2 extend = vec2((uPlaneSize.x), (uPlaneSize.y));
    vec2 coords = abs(uv) * (extend + uBorderRadius);
    vec2 delta = max(coords - extend, 0.);
    return length(delta);
}

void main() {

  vec2 ratio = vec2(
    min((uPlaneSize.x / uPlaneSize.y) / (uImageActiveSize.x / uImageActiveSize.y), 1.0),
    min((uPlaneSize.y / uPlaneSize.x) / (uImageActiveSize.y / uImageActiveSize.x), 1.0)
  );

  vec2 uv = vec2(
    vUv.x * ratio.x + (1.0 - ratio.x) * 0.5,
    vUv.y * ratio.y + (1.0 - ratio.y) * 0.5
  );

  vec2 ratio2 = vec2(
    min((uPlaneSize.x / uPlaneSize.y) / (uImageNextSize.x / uImageNextSize.y), 1.0),
    min((uPlaneSize.y / uPlaneSize.x) / (uImageNextSize.y / uImageNextSize.x), 1.0)
  );

  vec2 uv2 = vec2(
    vUv.x * ratio2.x + (1.0 - ratio2.x) * 0.5,
    vUv.y * ratio2.y + (1.0 - ratio2.y) * 0.5
  );

  vec2 uvMix = mix(uv, uv2, -uTransitionProgress);

  float dist = calcDistance(vUv);
  if (dist > uBorderRadius) discard;

  float alpha = ( vPosition.y + uMaskProgress ) > 0.5 ? 0.0 : 1.0;


  float aspect = uPlaneSize.y / uPlaneSize.x;
  float maxX = 1.0 - uBorderThickness;
  float minX = uBorderThickness;
  float maxY = maxX / aspect;
  float minY = minX / aspect;

  if (vUv.x < maxX && vUv.x > minX &&
      vUv.y < maxY && vUv.y > minY) {
    gl_FragColor = transition(uvMix);
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
  }

  gl_FragColor.a *= alpha; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
float calcDistance(vec2 uv) {
    vec2 extend = vec2((uPlaneSize.x), (uPlaneSize.y));
    vec2 coords = abs(uv) * (extend + uBorderRadius);
    vec2 delta = max(coords - extend, 0.);
    return length(delta);
}
```

This would do what you want if texture UV coordinates had a range of -1 to 1 — then all four corners would have coordinates of ±1 and get rounded. But they actually have a range of 0 to 1, so the only corner that is rounded is the one that *does* have coordinates of (1, 1), the top right.

You can fix this by rescaling the coordinates so they *are* symmetric that way:

```
float calcDistance(vec2 uv) {
    // Rescale UV to be -1 to 1
    vec2 positionInQuadrant = abs(uv * 2.0 - 1.0);

    vec2 extend = uPlaneSize;
    vec2 coords = positionInQuadrant * (extend + uBorderRadius);
    vec2 delta = max(coords - extend, 0.);
    return length(delta);
}
```

Note that because this stretches the coordinates to double the range, you will have to compensate for that by changing uPlaneSize too.

```
float calcDistance(vec2 uv) {
    // Rescale UV to be -1 to 1
    vec2 positionInQuadrant = abs(uv * 2.0 - 1.0);  // key change
    // Rescale uPlaneSize to compensate
    vec2 extend = uPlaneSize / 2.0;

    vec2 coords = positionInQuadrant * (extend + uBorderRadius);
    vec2 delta = max(coords - extend, 0.);
    return length(delta);
}
```

I tested this out by running the following shader in [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/new):

```
const float uBorderRadius = 20.0;

float calcDistance(vec2 uv) {
    vec2 positionInQuadrant = abs(uv * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec2 extend = vec2(iResolution) / 2.0;
    vec2 coords = positionInQuadrant * (extend + uBorderRadius);
    vec2 delta = max(coords - extend, 0.);
    return length(delta);
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    
    float dist = calcDistance(uv);
    if (dist > uBorderRadius) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    } else if (dist > 0.0) {
        fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    } else {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0 ,1.0);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that is a great explanation and it does work perfectly now. Really appreciate the detailed clarification.